# write function: is there a way to write only a part of the buffer?

Tags: c, buffer

I'm learning to use the write function and am trying to print only a part of a buffer array of chars.  So it looks like this:

```
char *tempChar;
char *buf;
buf=&tempChar;
read(0, buf, 10);

write(1, [???], 1);
```

I thought about putting buf[3] where the [???] is, but that didn't work.
I also thought about using tempChar[3], but that didn't work either.

Any ideas?  Thanks so much.

Comment: In practice, you should know that the `write` system call is costly, and you generally should avoid calling it for a single character (or even a small amount of bytes). For performance reasons, it is important to `write` quite big chunks of data (typically several kilobytes at least). So you need to buffer your data. Then, it is often better to use `<stdio.h>` and functions like `fopen`, `fprintf`, `fputs`, `fwrite` because they do the buffering for you. But don't forget to call `fflush` or `fclose`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `buf + 3`.  This is pointer arithmetic.  It takes buf and gives you a new pointer 3 characters down.  `buf[3]` is equivalent to `*(buf + 3)`.  Note the unwanted dereference.

As another note:

```
buf=&tempChar;
```

is probably not right.

That assigns the address of the tempChar variable to buf, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: thank you, this solved it.  Yes, you're right, I meant "char tempChar" not "char *tempChar"

Comment: Then you have another bug! 'char tempChar;' makes tempChar a single character. You obviously can't read 10 bytes into it.